# Why are my fixture objects not available in my Rails Test::Unit test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

According to [this Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing_rails_applications.html#_the_low_down_on_fixtures), if you create a fixture, it becomes available in your test class.

I have this fixture in `users.yml`:

```
<%
  stan = User.new
  stan.username = 'stan'
  stan.set_hashed_password('mysterio')
  stan.email = 'stan@abc.com'
%>

stan:
  username: <%= stan.username %>
  hashed_password: <%= stan.hashed_password %>
  password_salt: <%= stan.password_salt %>
  email: <%= stan.email %>
```

Following the Rails guide, I'm trying to access it like this:

```
class SessionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  @user = users(:stan)

  # ...

end
```

I get this error:

```
./test/functional/sessions_controller_test.rb:5: undefined method `users' for SessionsControllerTest:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:155:in `require'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys. I realized that I had various declarations and calls structured incorrectly. This isn't clearly explained in the guide I cited, but apparently `users(:stan)` only works inside a `should` block, or in pure Test::Unit inside a `test_` method.

Comment: Yes, if you use it outside of the test methods or outside a shoulda block then you're calling a class method, not an instance method.

Answer (score 8):

Try putting

```
fixtures :users
```

after your class declaration

Comment: This worked for me - even though I thought to myself "of course all fixtures are loaded" - they were not. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have

```
fixtures :all
```

In your test_helper.rb

Answer (score -1):

This is a SUPER old question, but I had a similar problem just now when going through the rails tutorial book.

I have a setup method at the beginning of my UsersLoginTest integration test, and for some reason, the fixture I was referencing in that, didn't seem to be working inside the tests. I had to have a line at the top of the test @user = users(:michael) to get it working.

In the end, I found that I had duplicated the Class declaration at the top of the file, by LAZY copy and pasting from the tutorial book. So if anyone else comes across this thread with a similar problem related to fixtures not working, check if you've made the same silly mistake as me, and duplicated the top of the file!

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end
```