# Rails 3.1, issues with fixtures and testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, fixtures

So, I am having some trouble running tests in Rails. When I ran 'Rake test' and I have something like this

```
http_basic_authenticate_with :name =>Hello.first.myhello, :password =>Hello.first.myhello
```

Inside my controller, I get an error

'method_missing': undefined method `myhello' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Clearly the fixtures aren't being loaded, is there anyway I can make them load and have this not fail? Using Rails 3.1.

Comment: I don't use testunit, but where did you actually setup data for this? In a seed.rb file? In some setup code for your step?

Comment: [Possibly related question: Why are my fixture objects not available in my Rails Test::Unit test?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523771/why-are-my-fixture-objects-not-available-in-my-rails-testunit-test)

Answer (score 0):

** edit: [possibly related SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523771/why-are-my-fixture-objects-not-available-in-my-rails-testunit-test)? Basically, put this in your test unit class:

```
fixtures :hellos
```

If that doesn't do it, could you paste the relevant parts of your fixture and test class?

**original:

I'm not sure about your experience level or your setup, so just to confirm that you are testing what you think you are testing, could you add this line before the line in your question?

```
Hello.create(:name => some_value, :password => some_value)
```

In case there is any confusion,

> undefined method `myhello' for nil:NilClass

indicates that you are not actually getting any records, not that you don't have the Hello model.

Comment: Right, it is what I am testing, and I realize that this means that I don't have any records. As mentioned I am running 'Rake test', I have fixtures that contain data, clearly however, they are not loading. The data is set up in fixtures/hellos.yml